# mysql coalesce for null values in joined table

Tags: mysql

The stucture of table `day` and `report` is as below.

**day**

```
id  day
1   sunday
2   monday
3   tuesday
4   thursday
5   friday
6   saturday
```

**report**

```
id  dta day ndx
1   10  1   1
2   15  2   1
3   14  3   1
4   15  4   1
5   12  5   1
6   11  6   1
7   55  1   2
8   23  2   2
9   10  3   2
10  19  4   2
```

Need to be group by `report.ndx`, so data would be managed as index wise

```
ndx-1, sunday-10, monday-15, tuesday-14, thursday-15, friday-12, saturday-11
ndx-2, sunday-55, monday-23, tuesday-10, thursday-19
```

Sql Syntax with group by

```
SELECT report.ndx AS ndx, GROUP_CONCAT(day.day,'-',report.dta) AS data 
FROM report 
LEFT JOIN day ON day.id = report.day 
GROUP BY report.ndx
```

**But requirment is placing null value if day is not in report table.** For example

```
ndx-2, sunday-55, monday-23, tuesday-10, thursday-19, friday-0, saturday-0
```

So what I tried with coalesce

```
SELECT report.ndx AS ndx, GROUP_CONCAT(day.day,'-',COALESCE(report.dta),'0') AS data 
FROM report 
LEFT JOIN day ON day.id = report.day 
GROUP BY report.ndx
```

But I think, as report is primary in `SQL JOIN` Statement, so coalesce is useless to use setting null value.

I tried with case when

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE 
                     WHEN day.id=report.day 
                     THEN CONCAT(day.day,'-',report.dta) 
                ELSE CONCAT(day.day,'-',0) END) AS data 
FROM report 
LEFT JOIN day ON 1=1 
GROUP BY report.ndx
```

But it prints once null value with day and again value with matched day in same index. For example

```
sunday-10, sunday-0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes:

- COALESCE requires at least 2 arguments to be meaningful but you have provided only 1 argument `report.dta`
- you are joining the tables in the wrong order. If you want to get all days from table `day` even if no record in table `report` references that day - then you should put `day` in the FROM clause and then join `report` on the left
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT ndx, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(day,'-',dta))
   FROM
    (SELECT d.id, d.day, IFNULL(dta,0) dta, IFNULL(ndx,1) ndx 
      FROM day d LEFT JOIN report r
       ON d.id=r.day AND ndx=1 
    UNION ALL
     SELECT d.id, d.day, IFNULL(dta,0) dta, IFNULL(ndx,2) ndx 
      FROM day d LEFT JOIN report r 
       ON d.id=r.day AND ndx=2) A
GROUP BY ndx
```

1. Make a `LEFT JOIN` query between `day` and `report` tables.
2. Separate the queries by `ndx` value and `UNION ALL` it.
3. Replace `NULL` values using `IFNULL(dta,0)` for `dta` and `IFNULL(ndx,[value])`; where the `[value]` is whatever value of `ndx` in `WHERE`.
4. Turn that query to become sub-query.
5. Type in the `SELECT ndx, GROUP_CONCAT(...` condition then `GROUP BY ndx`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e687a42d46f4c5233f0f72b2aa1f3558)